# How do I set Minimum characters in a Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I tried to set a minimum characters in the Textarea for comments. I like a user to enter a minimum characters before they can submit the form. I already have a code to check for maximum characters.

How do I modify this code to work with Minimum characters for comment textarea?

I added the new code in.

```
var maxComments = 500;
    function limComments(obj) {
        while(obj.value.length > maxComments) {
            obj.value = obj.value.replace(/.$/,'');
        }
    }
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: did you try `maxlength="500" minlength="5"` on the `textarea` itself

Comment: While loop??? Why not just `document.querySelector("[name=Q2C]").oninput=function() { this.value=this.value.substring(0,maxComments) }`

Comment: I have some boxes for comments. I like to have an alert if they enter less than required characters before they move to a new comment box. Reason I use While Loop is to prevent a user to paste a document in the comment box. I tried maxlength="500" minlength="5" but it won't alert any error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rely on the built-in properties, with JS for "backup". If for some reason you want to forgo the built-in, they could be replaced by, say `data-mincount="10"` and `data-maxcount="500"`.

If you're using an HTML5 compliant browser, with support for the `maxlength="500"` and `minlength="10"` properties, it will prevent more than 500 characters entered. While it doesn't directly affect the field for minimum, it will prevent the form from being submitted. The browser itself will then show the erroneous entry.

*EDIT:* Noticed the trimming of the input, updated code to reflect.

```js
function limComments(obj) {
  var charLimit = [obj.getAttribute('minlength'), obj.getAttribute('maxlength')];
  var fieldID = obj.getAttribute('id');

  if (obj.value.length >= charLimit[0] && obj.value.length <= charLimit[1]) {
    console.log("The comment in " + fieldID + " is just right.");
  } else if (obj.value.length > charLimit[1]) {
    console.log("The comment in " + fieldID + " is too long.");
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, charLimit[1]); // Truncate to first 500 characters
  } else {
    console.log("The comment in " + fieldID + " is too short.");
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="comment1">Comment 1</label>
<textarea rows="3" cols="85" maxlength="500" minlength="10" name="Q1C" onblur="limComments(this)" title="Comments" id="comment1" class="textarea" /></textarea>
<br>
<label for="comment2">Comment 2</label>
<textarea rows="3" cols="85" maxlength="500" minlength="10" name="Q2C" onblur="limComments(this)" title="Comments" id="comment2" class="textarea" /></textarea>
<br>
<label for="comment3">Comment 3</label>
<textarea rows="3" cols="85" maxlength="500" minlength="10" name="Q2C" onblur="limComments(this)" title="Comments" id="comment3" class="textarea" /></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried this code by typing 8 characters then moved to a new box, it doesn't alert anything. I added this code after else: alert("Please enter at least 150 characters"); I am using IE 11. Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran that's because - at the moment - it has `// Comment is too short - code some form of notice` in place. That's where you would place your `alert("too short")` (or something else, that won't annoy users) code.

Comment: Yes. I added alert for 3 // Comment is too short - code some form of notice, but it won't alert anything when I typed 8 characters in the first comment box, and moved to a second comment box. Thanks.

Comment: it's using the `minlength` in the text area, which I set to 10. You'll have to set yours to the number you want to trigger it. Also, if your `<textarea>` does _not_ have a `minlength` attribute, it will fail to match anything.

Comment: I did everything. <textarea rows="3" cols="85" name="Q1C" maxlength="500" minlength="150" onblur="limComments(this)" title="Comments" id="1" class="textarea" /></textarea> . Do you have an example for me to test it online? Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran I just updated it, with `console.log()`, to show the script running. I also set the comparatives to be inclusive (`<=` and `>=`).

Comment: I updated as your code but it doesn't do anything after I moved to a new Textarea box. it should say "comment too short" but it doesn't show any error. I am using IE 11. Do I have to  adjust anything on the IE browser? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my example, adding more boxes (and renaming IDs/names as required. You would need to use some form of debugging, to find what's happening in it now. Without a fresh example of your current code, I'm at a loss now.

Comment: Hi matthew, I've my code above. But it still doesn't do anything. Thanks.

Comment: I see in the code above, you maintained the `console.log(message)` I was using for testing - this only prints into the browser's console if you have it open. If you replace it with `alert(message)`, it should create an actual alert. You could also put in code to - for instance - add a class to the textarea, to highlight which one is wrong.